# SQLAlchemy error in Python 3.11 when trying to initialize a table; It used to work in Python 3.8

Tags: python

Running the code below. It used to run in version Python 3.8. Recently I upgraded to 3.11 and it stopped working. I upgraded both sqlalchemy and pyodbc.

I have longer code but posting up to the first step where it is failing.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sql
#from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from datetime import datetime as t
import pyodbc



connection_string = (
                    r"DRIVER={SQL Server};"
                    r"SERVER=Server_Name;" # Actual name redacted
                    r"Database=DB_Name;" # Actual name redacted
                    r"UID=Domain\Username;" # Actual name redacted
                    r"Trusted_Connection=yes;" 
                    )


connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc",query={"odbc_connect": connection_string}) # Creates full connection url from connection string
engine = sql.create_engine(connection_url, use_setinputsizes=False)
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = sql.MetaData()




initTable = sql.Table('Input_tickers', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine) # Specifys table to be queried
#mQuery = select(initTable) # Selects ztb_input_tickers from variable
#mResultProxy = connection.execute(mQuery) # Executes SQL query
#mResultSet = mResultProxy.fetchall() # Gets Query result
```

**Here is the error I get.**

```
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

= RESTART: C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\SimpleyCopyfromDB.py
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\SimpleyCopyfromDB.py", line 45, in <module>
    initTable = sql.Table('Input_tickers', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine) # Specifys table to be queried
  File "<string>", line 2, in __new__
  File "C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 283, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 435, in __new__
    return cls._new(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 489, in _new
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 485, in _new
    table.__init__(name, metadata, *args, _no_init=False, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 859, in __init__
    self._extra_kwargs(**kw)
  File "C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 1007, in _extra_kwargs
    self._validate_dialect_kwargs(kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 590, in _validate_dialect_kwargs
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'autoload'
```

Comment: I think the `autoload` parameter is invalid if you are using v2. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table